# sort with special sort number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, sort table and assign table

| SortID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | D |

I want assign mission to everyone, start with a special sortID
example: start with sortID 2, and change order next week.
result as below:

| Date | Week | MissionA | MissionB | MissionC | MissionD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/1/3 | 1 | C | D | A | B |
| 2021/1/4 | 1 | C | D | A | B |
| 2021/1/5 | 1 | C | D | A | B |
| 2021/1/6 | 1 | C | D | A | B |
| 2021/1/7 | 1 | C | D | A | B |
| 2021/1/8 | 1 | C | D | A | B |
| 2021/1/9 | 1 | C | D | A | B |
| 2021/1/10 | 2 | D | A | B | C |
| 2021/1/11 | 2 | D | A | B | C |

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried to solve the problem

Comment: we can't really help you unless you better specify your issue here. What DB are you using?

Comment: @Carlo Prato: The DBMS is Oracle obviously, and the DB is probably his own. Do you want to know what the assign table looks like? Me too :-)

Comment: Please show your assign table. Or is the result you are showing what the assign table should be filled with? Where do you get the days from? Do you want them generated? Where do you get the number of missions from? Is that simply the number of entries in the sort table?

Comment: sorry everyone, I didn't make it clear. I am new to oracle sql. MT0 answer my question and i know how to do it, thanks all ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not know the number of rows in the `sorts` table then you can generate the values as rows (instead of columns):

```sql
SELECT d.dt,
       d.week,
       MOD(d.week + s.sortid, s.num_sorts) AS mission,
       s.name
FROM   (
         SELECT DATE '2021-01-02' + LEVEL AS dt,
                CEIL(LEVEL / 7) AS week
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9
       ) d
       CROSS JOIN (
         SELECT sortid,
                name,
                COUNT(*) OVER() AS num_sorts
         FROM   sorts
       ) s
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sorts (SortID, Name) AS
SELECT 0, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'D' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DT | WEEK | MISSION | NAME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 03-JAN-21 | 1 | 1 | A |
> | 03-JAN-21 | 1 | 2 | B |
> | 03-JAN-21 | 1 | 3 | C |
> | 03-JAN-21 | 1 | 0 | D |
> | 04-JAN-21 | 1 | 1 | A |
> | 04-JAN-21 | 1 | 2 | B |
> | 04-JAN-21 | 1 | 3 | C |
> | 04-JAN-21 | 1 | 0 | D |
> | 05-JAN-21 | 1 | 1 | A |
> | 05-JAN-21 | 1 | 2 | B |
> | 05-JAN-21 | 1 | 3 | C |
> | 05-JAN-21 | 1 | 0 | D |
> | 06-JAN-21 | 1 | 1 | A |
> | 06-JAN-21 | 1 | 2 | B |
> | 06-JAN-21 | 1 | 3 | C |
> | 06-JAN-21 | 1 | 0 | D |
> | 07-JAN-21 | 1 | 1 | A |
> | 07-JAN-21 | 1 | 2 | B |
> | 07-JAN-21 | 1 | 3 | C |
> | 07-JAN-21 | 1 | 0 | D |
> | 08-JAN-21 | 1 | 1 | A |
> | 08-JAN-21 | 1 | 2 | B |
> | 08-JAN-21 | 1 | 3 | C |
> | 08-JAN-21 | 1 | 0 | D |
> | 09-JAN-21 | 1 | 1 | A |
> | 09-JAN-21 | 1 | 2 | B |
> | 09-JAN-21 | 1 | 3 | C |
> | 09-JAN-21 | 1 | 0 | D |
> | 10-JAN-21 | 2 | 2 | A |
> | 10-JAN-21 | 2 | 3 | B |
> | 10-JAN-21 | 2 | 0 | C |
> | 10-JAN-21 | 2 | 1 | D |
> | 11-JAN-21 | 2 | 2 | A |
> | 11-JAN-21 | 2 | 3 | B |
> | 11-JAN-21 | 2 | 0 | C |
> | 11-JAN-21 | 2 | 1 | D |

*Note: If you do not know how many columns there will be in the output, it is very difficult to `PIVOT` the columns to rows as SQL (not just Oracle) does not support dynamic pivoting. Pivoting dynamic data to columns would, typically, be something that is done in the middle tier (PHP, Java, C#, Python, etc.) application.*

---

If you know the number of rows in the `sorts` table then you can use conditional aggregation to pivot the columns to rows:

```sql
SELECT d.dt,
       d.week,
       MAX(
         CASE MOD(4 + MOD(3 + s.sortid - d.week, 4), 4)
         WHEN 0
         THEN s.name
         END
       ) AS missionA,
       MAX(
         CASE MOD(4 + MOD(3 + s.sortid - d.week, 4), 4)
         WHEN 1
         THEN s.name
         END
       ) AS missionB,
       MAX(
         CASE MOD(4 + MOD(3 + s.sortid - d.week, 4), 4)
         WHEN 2
         THEN s.name
         END
       ) AS missionC,
       MAX(
         CASE MOD(4 + MOD(3 + s.sortid - d.week, 4), 4)
         WHEN 3
         THEN s.name
         END
       ) AS missionD
FROM   (
         SELECT DATE '2021-01-02' + LEVEL AS dt,
                CEIL(LEVEL / 7) AS week
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9
       ) d
       CROSS JOIN sorts s
GROUP BY dt, week
ORDER BY dt
```

Which outputs:

> | DT | WEEK | MISSIONA | MISSIONB | MISSIONC | MISSIOND |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 03-JAN-21 | 1 | C | D | A | B |
> | 04-JAN-21 | 1 | C | D | A | B |
> | 05-JAN-21 | 1 | C | D | A | B |
> | 06-JAN-21 | 1 | C | D | A | B |
> | 07-JAN-21 | 1 | C | D | A | B |
> | 08-JAN-21 | 1 | C | D | A | B |
> | 09-JAN-21 | 1 | C | D | A | B |
> | 10-JAN-21 | 2 | D | A | B | C |
> | 11-JAN-21 | 2 | D | A | B | C |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ba925deab6c0ed7aedbeb78b6ab20e62)*